# Spring Scheduler task run with multiple timezones dateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have multiple timeZone customers wise and Application works with UTC.So, Normally I implemented

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 10 0 * * ?") // This scheduler will run at 00:10 AM daily And Send Notification.
```

But the problem is it runs on UTC time 12:10 AM; However, it may differ based on customer TimeZone

eg. UTC 00:10 AM In IST it's 5:40 AM so India's customer will get a notification at 05:40 AM instead of 00:10 AM in IST.

Require: I need to run a task(scheduler) at 00:10 AM in each customer time zone Not in Application TimeZone(UTC).

Comment: you can have it run every hour and check which timezone is now at 12:10 am or can use something more dynamic like quartz schedule calculate when things need to run and schedule it ahead of time.

Comment: "run every hour" - yes - or every 30 minutes to account for countries with 30 minute offsets (e.g. India), or even 15 minutes (Nepal)...

Comment: @locus2k Thanks for replay. But With this Logic have conflict or problem i.e(Default scheduler Runs with application timeZone such as UTC. Let's run scheduler every hour or 30 min and we check every timeZone time is now at 12:10 AM But there are chances that on the particular time it always surrounds time, not exact 12:10 AM) so we miss that 12:10 AM   time of particular timeZone //hope you understand

Comment: Run the scheduler every 30 minutes _starting at 12:10am_.

Comment: Also, it is worth considering timezones where some form of [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is observed. To avoid missing a report, or sending two on one day, you may prefer to pre-calculate each day's schedule in advance. This also applies to ad hoc adjustments which countries can implement, from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

user.timezone Java system property might help